# Does VisualStateManager.GoToState return when the animation completes?

Tags: wpf, silverlight

As the title mentions, does VisualStateManager.GoToState return once the state transition *completes* if I specify `UseAnimation = true`? Or does it return instantly and the animation runs later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension of VSM here that allows for executing a delegate after the transistion completes.

http://adammills.wordpress.com/2010/09/09/visualstatemanager-execute-after-transition-finished/

Comment: Unfortunately, the source is gone

Comment: Code can still be found here: https://code.google.com/archive/p/present/source/default/source

Answer (score 0):

The animations can take any amount of time, depending on the transitions that were authored.

As all transitions are implemented via storyboards and storyboards are running animations asynchronously, your code will return immediately and the animations will play on in the background (even zero-time ones do this).

Comment: Bummer, any way to get notified when the state transition completes?